# Equivalent canDisableShutterSound method in Android Camera2 API

Tags: android, audio, camera, shutter

Is there an equivalent **canDisableShutterSound** method in the Camera2 API?

I couldn't find any details about it, so I’m assuming the Camera2 API allows taking pictures without the shutter sound, but this is only my assumption because some countries enforce by law the shutter sound in smartphones, such as Japan, where the device default shutter sound is played at the time of picture taking regardless of whether the app plays another shutter sound or not. At least this is the case for the legacy Camera API.

The use case is to be able to ignore the app custom shutter sound if detected that the device will be also play its own audio, which in the old camera API was resolved by using the **canDisableShutterSound** method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera2 does not play any sounds automatically.

Instead, the camera-using application is required to follow the expectations on shutter sound enforcement in whatever country it is available in. [MediaActionSound](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaActionSound.html) can be used for this.